# case insensitve in Python 3.2 txt

Tags: python, case, case-insensitive

```
x = input("Please enter the character you wish to search for:")

file = open("C:\\Users\\Murphy\\Desktop\\names.txt", "r")

a_string = file.read().count(x)

print(a_string)
```

The code works fine, but I don't know how to make the character search case insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the `.lower` string method.  You can make sure `x` is lower case as well as the output of `file.read()` using it.

Answer (score 0):

`a_string = file.read().lower().count(x.lower())`

Comment: ty. I've used way too much ruby lately :)

Comment: Interesting.  I've thought about trying to learn ruby once or twice.  I can just never seem to tear myself away from python ...

Comment: ruby is pretty and fun to write but python is more powerful and it's got better libraries. sometimes I'm thinking about switching back to python myself...